# Are weak and strong pareto optimality equivalent in terms of efficiency and equity?

Tags: general-equilibrium

Can I claim that the concepts of weak and strong Pareto optimality are equivalent both in terms of efficiency and equity among agents and generate the same level of social welfare?
I know that when preferences are monotonic and continuous, weakly pareto optimal is same as strongly pareto optimal.

Comment: Hi! Can you please define the terms you use? (Efficiency, equity, social welfare.)

Comment: I guess they are used in its general meaning. This was a true/false statement that i came across.